# getting null value in @Html.DropDownList in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select

I am getting null value by selecting dropdownlist item in controller.[I saw by doing in debug mode]

Here is my code

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var jobStatusList = new SelectList(new[] 
    {
        new { ID = "1", Name = "Full Time" },
        new { ID = "2", Name = "Part Time" },
    },
    "ID", "Name", 1);

    ViewData["JobStatusList"] = jobStatusList;
}

public ActionResult Create(StaffRegistrationViewModel staffRegistrationViewModel)
{
    //Here is my code
}
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "StaffRegistration", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{   
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.DropDownList("jobStatusList",ViewData["JobStatusList"] as SelectList)
}
```

In staffRegistrationViewModel getting null value in Status field.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is rendering a dropdown element with name attribute value `jobStatusList`. If your view models property name is `Status` it will not be mapped by the model binder because the names do not match.

You need to render a SELECT element with the name `Status`

```
@Html.DropDownList("Status", ViewData["JobStatusList"] as SelectList)
```

But if you are already using a view model, i would recommend adding a property of type `List<SelectListItem>` to pass the data instead of using ViewData/ViewBag along with the `DropDownListFor` helper method.

```
@model StaffRegistrationViewModel 
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "StaffRegistration"))
{
   @Html.DropDownListFor(a=>a.Status,Model.StatusList)
}
```

Assuming your view model has a StatusList proeprty

```
public class StaffRegistrationViewModel 
{
   public int Status { set;get;}
   public List<SelectListItem> StatusList { set;get;}
}
```

and your GET action loaded the list to this property

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var list = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "Full Time"},
        new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "Part Time"}
    };
    var vm=new StaffRegistrationVm { StatusList=list };
    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: can you provide me that List<SelectListItem> syntax that how I can adding property and call the view dropdownlist.